# Linking different site extensions

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, google-search

I'm the owner of a domain ajrecruit and from that domain I own 4 extensions.

```
ajrecruit.be

ajrecruit.com

ajrecruit.eu

ajrecruit.nl
```

Now my original site is `ajrecuit.be` and is build in WordPress.

My question now is what is the best practice in order that when people use the `.com .nl .eu` all get redirected to `ajrecruit.be`.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not asking who to redirect a page as I know how to do this. My question is what is the best practice so `Google` picks up the different extensions as well?

Do I just redirect from all extensions to mu `www.ajrecruit.be` domain?
What about my `sitemap`? Do I put the other extensions in my sitemap?

I hope it's a bit clear as I'm having trouble to explain it in English.

Comment: don't include your secondary site URL in your primary sitemap.xml, and simply put a cPanel redirection to your primary domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used for this task 301 redirects, it's easy and convenient.